# Improving query performance from mysql slow log query

Tags: mysql, relational-database, prestashop, rds, infrastructure

We are using Prestashop as an e-commerce application and for the mobile application we used the same database and Prestashop architecture and almost using the same queries from core PrestaShop.

For some of the queries that we are using in our NODE Js API give us RDS (MySQL) CPU spike up to 100% when the traffic spikes up.

RDS configuration: db.m4.xlarg,4vCPU, 16 GB RAM

Slow Query (This query only appears in slow query logs when traffic is high) :

```
    EXPLAIN SELECT t1.id_product,
    t1.position,
    t1.price,
    t1.quantity,
    t1.reserve_stock,
    t1.name,
    t1.link_rewrite hyphen_name,
    t1.id_category_default,
    t1.id_sub_category,
    t1.is_back_in_stock,
    (SELECT link_rewrite FROM pml_category_lang WHERE id_category = 36 AND id_shop = 1 AND id_lang = 1 LIMIT 1) category_link_rewrite,
    CONCAT('[', t1.images, ']') images,
    t3.reduction,
    t3.reduction_type,
    IF(t3.reduction,
    IF(t3.reduction_type = 'percentage', ROUND((t1.price - (t3.reduction * t1.price))),
    ROUND(t1.price - t3.reduction)),
    t1.price) discounted_price
    FROM
    (SELECT ps.id_product, ps.id_category_default, ps.is_back_in_stock, cp.position, ROUND ((7/100) * ps.price * 1 + ps.price * 1) price,
    sa.quantity, sa.reserve_stock, pl.name, p.date_add, pl.link_rewrite,
    (SELECT pml_category.id_category FROM pml_category
    LEFT JOIN pml_category_product ON pml_category_product.id_category = pml_category.id_category
    AND pml_category_product.id_shop = 1
    WHERE id_parent = 36 AND pml_category_product.id_category IS NOT NULL AND pml_category_product.id_product = cp.id_product LIMIT 1) AS id_sub_category,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('{"id_image":', i.id_image, ',', '"position":', i.position, ',', '"cover":', ims.cover, '}')) images
    FROM pml_category_product cp
    JOIN pml_product_shop ps
    ON cp.id_product = ps.id_product AND cp.id_shop = ps.id_shop 
    JOIN pml_product p
    ON p.id_product = cp.id_product
    AND p.id_category_default = 36
    JOIN pml_stock_available sa
    ON cp.id_product = sa.id_product AND cp.id_shop = sa.id_shop AND sa.id_product_attribute = 0 AND sa.quantity > 0 
    JOIN pml_product_lang pl
    ON cp.id_product = pl.id_product AND cp.id_shop = pl.id_shop AND pl.id_lang = 1
    JOIN pml_image i
    ON cp.id_product = i.id_product
    JOIN pml_image_shop ims
    ON ims.id_image = i.id_image AND ims.id_shop = 1
    WHERE ps.id_shop = 1
    AND ps.active = 1 AND i.smartly !=1
    AND ps.visibility = 'both'
    GROUP BY cp.id_product) t1 join pml_pomelo_rank pr on t1.id_product = pr.id_product and pr.id_shop = 1 and (pr.alltime_regular_cr > 2 or pr.alltime_qty_sold > 100) and pr.id_product != 14930 and pr.id_product not in (select id_product_2 from pml_accessory where id_product_1 = 14930) 
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT t2.* FROM
    (SELECT id_product, id_specific_price_rule, reduction, reduction_type, `from`, `to`
    FROM pml_specific_price
    WHERE id_shop IN (0, 1) and id_currency IN (0,1)
    AND ((`from` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR '2017-08-15 13:15:33' >= `from`) AND (`to` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR '2017-08-15 13:15:33' <= `to`))
    ORDER BY id_product ASC, id_specific_price_rule ASC) t2
    GROUP BY t2.id_product) t3
    ON t1.id_product = t3.id_product ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0, 4;
```

Current we are trying to find if it would be good to increase RDS infrastructure size or Queries like this needs improvements.

Note: this is exactly the same query that Prestashop core uses for category page

any suggestion or help regarding query optimization or infrastructure RDS (config) optimization for such queries would be helpful.

RDS GRAPH:
[image: RDS graph spikes are correlated with traffic]

[image: EXPLAIN output for the query]

Comment: Is that a Prestasshop query, or one you made? Also, the order by rand(), if you have many rows, can be realy slow.

Comment: Although I doubt that anyone will do a deep analysis of a 50-line-20-joins-10-subquery-query, the least you could do is to actually add the output of the explain to at least give them a fighting chance. Also: while more ram is always a good idea (although you also might want to check your mysql config, as mysql has to actually *use* that ram to make additional ram useful), if this is the only one in your slow log, you should check if you need that query in this form, or if it can be simplified. Somebody created it for you because you had some requirements, so maybe recheck these requirements.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for the response. what I am looking here what if someone has requirements for such queries then instead of modifying can CPU utilization be improved by configuring specific MySQL configuration parameters. right now I am using AWS RDS default configuration.

Or if I can somehow increase it by adding a certain index on tables or rewrite it another way around.

Regarding ram usage , we never see spike in RAM usage anytime

Comment: If you can improve your query by adding indexes can only be answered if you, as mentioned before, add the `explain` output (and details about the indexes listed there) - all that assuming someone is willing to go through your query in detail. For innodb, ram will not spike. The buffer gets filled, and not freed, just replaced. If the required data is in the buffer, it can be used from there, if not (e.g. as the buffer is not big enough), it has to (slowly!!) read the data from disk. So check the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`-setting - although it is not even clear if you use innodb.

Comment: Generally speaking: if your intention is not to optimize your query (which is a programming question), but to optimize your server configuration (which is an administration question), your question would fit better on dba.stackexchange.com. Still, you would need to add more details about your setup. See e.g [How large should be mysql innodb_buffer_pool_size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size) for general tips that you can use in your setup too (assuming you are using innodb), or what you need to include in your question.

Comment: @sadlyblue this query we made for from PrestaShop controller with some customization

Comment: @Solarflare I will add EXPLAIN output

Comment: Without a more detailed analysis (e.g. if every join/subquery/condition is necessary, and thus if it can be optimized in priniciple), the explain suggests to add an index for `pml_product(id_category_default, id_product)`, also your inner query `t3` should be rewritten (it selects and orders everything in `t2`, then groups the result of that by `id_product` - so just group by that directly and remove the inner-inner-subquery `t2`). There might be more things to improve, but would require more time. Also it's not clear how much it impacts the speed (you have relatively small tables after all).

Comment: Also, although I don't know the overall requirements/intention of this query, it might be possible to precalculate this, e.g. update a helper table once every 10 minutes with all (or enough random) suggested items for every category, and pick rows at random from this table based on the current category (excluding the current item/accessory-condition). If the algorithm heavily depends on the current item (and not just to exlude them in the result), it might be more complicated (or maybe not worth the effort, as the table would get too big to contain 100th of proposed items for every item).

Comment: ORDER BY in a subquery without LIMIT has no meaning, so your query is likely technically wrong & possibly just wrong although possibly coincidentally ok given a particular implementation. Also ORDER BY RAND() can be very slow & not do what you want--google re that & alternatives. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for your comment. By rewriting the query and removing sub query t2  affected the average response time to 30% less.